# make javascript module global?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to execute a function from within a script. It shows no error but also doesnt execute the function.

```
file.mjs
    
function test() {
  console.log("test")
}
```

This is my html:

```
index.html 
    <head>
       <script type="module" src="file.mjs">
    </head>
    <body>
       <button type="button" id="Submit">Submit</button>
       <script>       
         document.getElementById('Submit').addEventListener('click', test);
       </script>
    </body>
```

This worked fine using 2 separate scripts, to make it global I was using type="text/javascript".
But since my file.mjs is actually importing a library I had to set it as type="module" and the function wont execute. Is there a way to make the module scope global?

Comment: You can't have a script element with code *and* a `src` attribute. Have one with the `src`, then after it one with code.

Comment: You need to export that function if you plan to import it anywhere

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Before I go on*, there's a big problem that needs addressing:
Your syntax is wrong. If you want to import a script, that tag must have the src attribute and nothing within the tag. If you want to execute an "inline" script, it should NOT have the src attribute, so what you should have is two script tags, one to import the module, the other to execute your inline code.

Now, I'm not sure what you mean by "global". To obtain true "globalness", you would have to define your variable in the global object (`window` or `globalThis`) like so:

```js
// file.mjs
function test() { ... }
window["test"] = test;
```

Then in your regular script you could just do `document.getElementById('Submit').addEventListener('click', test);`.
That sort of completely destroys the purpose of JS modules though, as it's supposed to be an "import/export" model.

Ignoring the "global" part of your question: if you want to use modules for what they're worth, you would be importing and exporting them, and you would only (almost always) link a `<script type="module">` in your HTML if it *only* imports and *never* exports (exporting would be useless). The reason you need `type="module"` is to tell the browser that you're operating on modules so it'll allow you to import/export. With that said, your code would look like this:

```js
// file.mjs
export function test() { ... }
```

And in your HTML, you would only need *one* script tag (that goes right before the ending body tag):

```html
<script type="module">
  import { test } from "/path/to/file.mjs";
  document.getElementById('Submit').addEventListener('click', test);
</script>
```

I hope that clears it up for you, and [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) if you need them.

Comment: Ok, I have changed it but the main problem remains, I am getting the "Uncaught ReferenceError: test is not defined" issue, this doesn't happen if I set the first script as text/javascript. Is there a way to make the function global if I set is as module?

Currently I have
<head>
    <script type="module" src="file.mjs"> </script>   
</head>
<body>
          <button type="button" id="Submit">Submit</button>
          <script>
            document.getElementById('Submit').addEventListener('click', test);
          </script>
</body>

Comment: @Msantamaria see edit.